# Почему возвращается json, а не xml в spring-boot приложении?

Tags: java, xml, rest, spring-boot

Есть приложение на spring-boot.
Controller:

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Customer> findAllCustomers() {
    return customerService.findAllCustomers();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    customerService.addCustomer(customer);
}
```

Model:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
@XmlRootElement(name="customer")
public class Customer{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Customer() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

И есть промежуточный сервис, связь между jpa и рестами.

Если я отправляю реквест на создание кастомера -

```
<customer>
    <id>first</id>
    <name>first name of metric</name>
</customer>
```

Все хорошо, в базе заведется кастомер.
Но, при попытке получить всех кастомеров, я получаю их в формате JSON.
Как это поправить, мне требуется получать от приложения кастомеров в формате xml в body?

Comment: попробуй указать заголовки accetp и content-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось добавлением зависимости

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

После этого все заработало.